# SQL Query: Select rows with repeated values across different columns

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that contains goalscorer information for a list of soccer matches. The table is structured like this:

| ID | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 | S5 | S6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 11 | 18 | 9 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 10 | 3 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 10 | 11 | 11 | 18 | 11 | 0 |
| 4 | 11 | 11 | 18 | 9 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 7 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

In this table, `ID` corresponds to an individual match ID - where as the numbers under each `Sx` column identify individual players and are cross-referenced with another table.

The following query lets me identify instances where player **11** scored more than once

```
SELECT * 
FROM `matchscorer` WHERE (`S1` = '11' AND (`S2` = '11' OR `S3` = '11' OR `S4` = '11' OR `S5` = '11' OR `S6` = '11')) OR (`S2` = '11' AND (`S3` = '11' OR `S4` = '11' OR `S5` = '11' OR `S6` = '11')) OR (`S3` = '11' AND (`S4` = '11' OR `S5` = '11' OR `S6` = '11')) OR (`S4` = '11' AND (`S5` = '11' OR `S6` = '11')) OR (`S5` = '11' AND (`S6` = '11'));
```

This returns the rows in which **11** appears more than once across the various columns – and I can then manually count those rows to get a total for how many times that happened.

What I wish to achieve, however, is a query that will identify occurrences throughout the table such as this for *all* players, then (I think) using `GROUP BY` to then output a list showing how many times a player scored more than once e.g. Player 11 - 3, Player 10 - 2.

The main blocker I have at the moment is adapting the query from a single player (**11**) to *any* player. Nothing I've found through research so far seems to focus on this type of query. Should I instead use `SELECT DISTINCT` or `COUNT DISTINCT` statements to get the desired output.

Is it then possible to isolate the query even further for instances of a player scoring just twice, or thrice, or even four times? Would this require something like `count = 3`?

Comment: Why the PHP tag?

Comment: What is S1, S2, etc. Maybe 'Score 1', 'Score 2'? If so, what if there are more than 6 in a match?

Comment: I would reconsider, if possible ofcourse, how this table is setup. I'd split it up in tables matches (with match_id) and goalscorers (with match_id player_id). Then it's a lot easier to do things like this.

Comment: And how do you know to which team the player belongs?

Comment: You can use a [`LATERAL JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) to normalise your data ([example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/KTsdUDV5)), but this begs the question (and as others have alluded to), why not just store normalised data in the first place?

Comment: @lukas.j - You are right. S1 denotes Scorer 1 and so on. I should have noted this data is for ONE team only. The columns in the actual table go up to S11, which is the club's record win and 99% unlikely to ever be matched.

Comment: @GarethD - The table's usage has evolved significantly since it was first created and did not review its structure at a point when changes were perhaps possible.

Comment: *the rows in which 11 appears more than once across the various columns* ```WHERE (S1 = 11) + (S2 = 11) + (S3 = 11) + (S4 = 11) + (S5 = 11) + (S6 = 11) > 1```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL ≥ 8.0.14, you can `CROSS JOIN` to a [lateral derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) to unpivot the data, as suggested by GarethD in the comments:

```sql
WITH match_goals (match_id, player_id, num_goals) AS (
    SELECT m.ID, s.player_id, COUNT(*)
    FROM matchscorer m
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT S1 UNION ALL SELECT S2 UNION ALL SELECT S3 UNION ALL SELECT S4 UNION ALL
        SELECT S5 UNION ALL SELECT S6 UNION ALL SELECT S7 UNION ALL SELECT S8 UNION ALL
        SELECT S9 UNION ALL SELECT S10 UNION ALL SELECT S11
    ) AS s (player_id)
    WHERE s.player_id > 0
    GROUP BY m.ID, s.player_id
)
SELECT
    player_id,
    SUM(num_goals = 1) AS scored_1,
    SUM(num_goals = 2) AS scored_2,
    SUM(num_goals = 3) AS scored_3,
    SUM(num_goals = 4) AS scored_4
FROM match_goals
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY player_id;
```

Or, if you are using MySQL < 8.0.14, you can use a `CROSS JOIN` to a derived table and then use the [CASE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case) to switch columns:

```sql
SELECT
    player_id,
    SUM(num_goals = 1) AS scored_1,
    SUM(num_goals = 2) AS scored_2,
    SUM(num_goals = 3) AS scored_3,
    SUM(num_goals = 4) AS scored_4
FROM (
    SELECT match_id, player_id, COUNT(*) AS num_goals
    FROM (
        SELECT ID AS match_id,
            CASE n.s
                WHEN  1 THEN S1
                WHEN  2 THEN S2
                WHEN  3 THEN S3
                WHEN  4 THEN S4
                WHEN  5 THEN S5
                WHEN  6 THEN S6
                WHEN  7 THEN S7
                WHEN  8 THEN S8
                WHEN  9 THEN S9
                WHEN 10 THEN S10
                WHEN 11 THEN S11
            END AS player_id,
            n.s
        FROM matchscorer
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT 1 AS s UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL
            SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11
        ) n
        HAVING player_id > 0
    ) t1
    GROUP BY match_id, player_id
) t2
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY player_id;
```

For the sample data provided, both of the above queries will output:

| player_id | scored_1 | scored_2 | scored_3 | scored_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 18 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

---

As suggested by Sitethief in the comments, you really should consider restructuring your data. If you create a new table with `(match_id, player_id, goal_index)`, you can easily populate it using the inner queries above. You could replace the existing `matchscorer` table with a view so that existing SELECT queries still work. Then you would only need to update parts of your application that write to the table. Easy for me to say with no knowledge of the scope/scale of your app ;-)

---

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VQpUgVpE).

Comment: I've used the ```cross join``` method as I am using MySQL < 8.0.14 – and it's done the trick @user1191247. The data structure was designed for a much simpler use at first and now has some more complex demands being put on it (such as this). While it feels past the point of no return, I'll consider restructuring as per yours and other comments.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming Sx columns are indexes of goals scored*

You can create a new table with the following columns:
match_id   |   player   |   goal_index

Then, you can group this table by `match_id` and `player` columns, and count how many times each player scored.
From there you should be able to easily find players who scored in `N` games.

```
SELECT
match_id, player, count(*) as goals_scored
FROM
(SELECT 
`ID` as match_id, `S1` as player, '1' as goal_index
FROM `matchscorer`
WHERE `S1`<>0

UNION ALL

SELECT 
`ID` as match_id, `S2` as player, '2' as goal_index
FROM `matchscorer`
WHERE `S2`<>0

SELECT 
`ID` as match_id, `S3` as player, '3' as goal_index
FROM `matchscorer`
WHERE `S3`<>0

SELECT 
`ID` as match_id, `S4` as player, '4' as goal_index
FROM `matchscorer`
WHERE `S4`<>0

SELECT 
`ID` as match_id, `S5` as player, '5' as goal_index
FROM `matchscorer`
WHERE `S5`<>0

SELECT 
`ID` as match_id, `S6` as player, '6' as goal_index
FROM `matchscorer`
WHERE `S6`<>0) as converted_table
GROUP BY 1,2
```